# Linq query to custom order by based on number of tags repeated in comma separated list

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, lambda

I have a list like below

```
  ID        Tags                 Name
  1   acronym, address            one
  2   applet, abbr, embed         two
  3   iframe, abbr                three
  4   abbr, bgsound, bdo          four
  5   img, acronym                five
```

I want to get the list in an order based on most repeated tags Like below

```
  ID        Tags                 Name      
  2   applet, abbr, embed         two
  3   iframe, abbr                three      
  4   abbr, bgsound, bdo          four
  1   acronym, address            one
  5   img,  acronym               five
```

Please help me with how to get it using c# lambda expression in LINQ.

Comment: What do you mean by most repeated?

Comment: here tag 'abbr' is repeated 3 times and acronym is repeated 2 times I need the order by based on most repeated tag

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: obj.OrderBy(item => preferences.Contains(item.DocumentTags)).ToList();

Here preferences is the list of order I need ex: List<string> = new List<string>() { 'abbr','acronym' }; 

But result is not getting as expected.

Comment: `var mostFrequentTag = myList.SelectMany(item => item.Tags).GroupBy(tag => tag).OrderByDescending(chunk => chunk.Count()).FirstOrDefault().Key;`

Answer (score 0):

[Demo on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sMiBmz)

You just need 2 steps:

1. Group each `tag` with the number of repeats accordingly. i.e: `{"Key":"abbr","Value":3}`
2. Loop through data then gets the biggest `weight` of each `tags` accordingly. After that, you can select result by `OrderByDescending(p => p.Weight)`

```
    var data = new []
            { 
                new SampleData{ ID = 1, Tags = new []{ "acronym", "address" }, Name = "one" },
                new SampleData{ ID = 2, Tags = new []{ "applet", "abbr", "embed" }, Name = "two" },
                new SampleData{ ID = 3, Tags = new []{ "iframe", "abbr" }, Name = "three" },
                new SampleData{ ID = 4, Tags = new []{ "abbr", "bgsound", "bdo" }, Name = "four" },
                new SampleData{ ID = 5, Tags = new []{ "img", "acronym" }, Name = "five" },
            };
            var orderedKeyMapping = data.SelectMany(p => p.Tags).GroupBy(tag => tag).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count()).OrderByDescending(p => p.Value);
            var result = data.Select(p => new 
                                     { 
                                         SampleData = p,  
                                         Weight = orderedKeyMapping.FirstOrDefault(o => p.Tags.Any(tag => o.Key.Equals(tag))).Value
                                     }).OrderByDescending(p => p.Weight)
                                       .Select(p => p.SampleData); 

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

**Updated**

*Tags repeated in comma separated list*, [Demo on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AiHEde)

```
var orderedKeyMapping = data.SelectMany(p => p.Tags.Split(',')).Select(x => x.Trim())
                                .GroupBy(tag => tag)
                                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key.ToString(), g => g.Count())
                                .OrderByDescending(p => p.Value);
        var result = data.Select(p => new 
                                 { 
                                     SampleData = p,  
                                     Weight = orderedKeyMapping.FirstOrDefault(o => p.Tags.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).Any(tag => o.Key.Equals(tag))).Value
                                 }).OrderByDescending(p => p.Weight)
                                   .Select(p => p.SampleData); 

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

**Output**

```
[
  {"ID":2,"Tags":["applet","abbr","embed"],"Name":"two"},
  {"ID":3,"Tags":["iframe","abbr"],"Name":"three"},
  {"ID":4,"Tags":["abbr","bgsound","bdo"],"Name":"four"},
  {"ID":1,"Tags":["acronym","address"],"Name":"one"},
  {"ID":5,"Tags":["img","acronym"],"Name":"five"}
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Chintu